# Reading a graph with irregular intervals

Tags: graphing-functions

This graph represents a large range along the x-axis, but I'm unsure how to read such a graph reliably. For instance, if I wanted to find 2 on the x-axis, what vertical line would I use, and more to the point, why are there two vertical lines between 1 and 3? Similarly, the two lines between 100 and 300, what indication is there on what numbers they represent?

This is from an electrical datasheet, and I've already been told that this datasheet is sub-standard, but even so, irregular intervals on the graphs of datasheets is rather common.

How are they used?

P.S: Being absolutely clueless, I'm unsure if I've tagged this question correctly.

[image: Figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the lines between 1 and 3 are 1.5 and 2.
Including 1.5 gives a more equal spacing to the grid, since the largest gap is between 2 and 1.
Also, observe that the distance between 1.5 and 2 is the same as the distance between 3 and 4 (since they have the same ration and we have a logarithmic scale).
There is also a horizontal line between 100 and 200 which probably 150, so it's not unlikely to have the same on both axes.
Using comparisons like this can help you identify the unnumbered lines.